# I need to pass variable values form a bat file to a perl script

Tags: perl

I have a bat file named exp.bat that runs exp.pl a perl script. I need to pass the values to the perl scipt when i run bat from my command prompt.Is that possible.TIA

Comment: Save the value to a file? Or invoke the bat file from perl with the argument containing the value, them have the bat file accept such an argument?

Answer (score 4):

minimal .pl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print join "*", @ARGV;
```

minimal .bat:

```
@perl exp.pl %*
```

usage/demo:

```
exp.bat a "b c" d
a*b c*d
```