# How to pass a parameter value from a batch file to a perl script?

Tags: perl, batch-file

I want to pass value of a variable say "x" used inside a perl script from a batch file (which invokes the perl script). Can someone show with a simple example how it is done?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [I need to pass variable values form a bat file to a perl script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16689400/176646), [How can I pass on my Bash loop variable to the Perl interpreter?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8974493/176646), [How to use shell variables in perl command call in a bash shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13093709/176646)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command should be

```
perl myscript.pl "$x"
```

and the Perl script will find the value of `x` in `$ARGV[0]`

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to pass value of a variable say "x" used inside a perl script from a batch file*

This doesn't quite make sense. Are you asking how to pass the value of a batch variable to a Perl script?

In batch files, variables are interpolated using `%NAME%`, so you'd use

```
perl script.pl "%X%"
```

In the script, the parameters are accessed via `@ARGV`.

```
set X=abc
perl -e"my ($x) = @ARGV; print qq{$x\n};" "%X%"
```